# Angular mapbox-gl-draw "MapboxDraw is not a constructor"

Tags: angular, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I am using mapbox-gl in an Angular 8 application and am trying to add the mapbox-gl-draw feature. I have installed it through cpm (`cpm i @mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw`), added the css file and added two lines of code:

```
buildMap() {
  this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: this.style,
    zoom: 10,
    center: [this.lng, this.lat]
  });

  var draw = new MapboxDraw();
  this.map.addControl(draw);

}
```

This produces the following error in the console:

> ERROR TypeError: _mapbox_mapbox_gl_draw_dist_mapbox_gl_draw__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.MapboxDraw is not a constructor

(The app continues to function.)

The only solution I was able to find online suggests that I should change the import from:

```
import { MapboxDraw } from '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/dist/mapbox-gl-draw';
```

to

```
import * as MapboxDraw from 'mapbox-gl-draw';
```

This required re-installing map-gl-draw using the following command on npm:

> npm i map-gl-draw

Whilst re-installing npm notified me that this command has now deprecated and been replaced by the command I used originally:

```
cpm i @mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw
```

The installation completed regardless and now my app no longer functions and produces the error:

> ./node_modules/jsonlint-lines/lib/jsonlint.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in...

Is this progress? There are questions and answers about resolving this 'fs' error in Angular and I have tried suggestions such as introducing a custom webpack without success. I understand that the default Angular webpack doesn't load fs. The fact that I used the wrong cpm installation to get to this stage, however, makes me think I'm on the wrong path regardless.

**UPDATE** It is now functioning after I introduced the following to my angular.json file:

```
"browser": {
    "fs": false
}
```

This all feels very hacky though as npm clearly stated that I am now using a deprecated version.

Comment: Good explanation of an identical situation I experience as well.